# R - create a timeseries from filenames

Tags: r, time-series

I have 900 files named like `20120412_bwDD2yYa.txt`. The first part up to the _ is in the year-month-day format. Some days have multiple files associated with them.

I'd like to use the dates extracted from the file names as data to compile a timeseries where the dates are the x axis and the number of files are the y axis.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi there, could you add some more examples of the file names? What is particularly important are the days with multiple files. Could you give an example of a date and the files associated with that date?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with Base R. Since the question does not include a reproducible example, we'll simulate the file names, parse out the dates, and create the counts by date.

```
# use list.files() to extract files from directory
files <- list.files(path="./data",pattern="*.txt",full.names = FALSE)

# simulate result from list.files()
files <- c("20120101_aaa.txt","20120101_bbb.txt","20120102_ccc.txt")

# extract dates from file names 
date <- as.Date(substr(files,1,8),"%Y%m%d")

df <- data.frame(date,count = rep(1,length(date)))
aggregate(count ~ date,data = df, sum)
```

...and the output:

```
        date count
1 2012-01-01     2
2 2012-01-02     1
```

### dplyr solution

A solution with `dplyr::summarise()` looks like this:

```
files <- list.files(path="./data",pattern="*.txt",full.names = FALSE)
# simulate result from list.files() 
files <- c("20120101_aaa.txt","20120101_bbb.txt","20120102_ccc.txt")
library(dplyr)
data.frame(date=as.Date(substr(files,1,8),"%Y%m%d")) %>% 
     group_by(date) %>% summarise(count = n())


# A tibble: 2 x 2
  date       count
  <date>     <int>
1 2012-01-01     2
2 2012-01-02     1
```

### Accounting for dates with no files

In response to a comment on my answer, here is a solution that fills in gaps in the file list where there are days with 0 files. We take the minimum and maximum dates from the file list and create a data frame containing the sequence of dates. Then we `left_join()` this with the previously aggregated data, and recode NA values for `count` to 0.

```
# create a gap in dates with files
files <- c("20120101_aaa.txt","20120101_bbb.txt","20120102_ccc.txt",
           "20120104_aaa.txt","20120104_aab.txt","20120104_aac.txt")
library(dplyr)
data.frame(date=as.Date(substr(files,1,8),"%Y%m%d")) %>% 
     group_by(date) %>% summarise(count = n()) -> fileCounts
# create df with all dates, left_join() and recode NA to 0
data.frame(date = as.Date(min(fileCounts$date):max(fileCounts$date),
                                    origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
     left_join(.,fileCounts) %>% 
     mutate(count = if_else(is.na(count),0,as.numeric(count)))
```

...and the output:

```
Joining, by = "date"
        date count
1 2012-01-01     2
2 2012-01-02     1
3 2012-01-03     0
4 2012-01-04     3
```

Comment: Nice. Could you include a scenario for preparing the time series, providing for gaps in the dates i.e. days with 0 files?

Comment: @BroVic - see my updated answer for a solution that accounts for dates with no files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` to count frequencies and then `stack` it to get a dataframe.

Using  @Len Greski's `files`.

```
files <- c("20120101_aaa.txt","20120101_bbb.txt","20120102_ccc.txt")
stack(table(as.Date(sub('_.*', '', files),"%Y%m%d")))[2:1]

#         ind values
#1 2012-01-01      2
#2 2012-01-02      1
```